# Plot seperate seasonal plots with datetime dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
    Date    station_name    BD_val      TEMIS_val   ratio       longitude   latitude
0   2003-01 29              295.448387  291.225806  -1.429211   158.950 -   54.500
1   2003-01 57              282.258065  279.290323  -1.051429   -26.130     -75.360
2   2003-01 57              282.258065  279.290323  -1.051429   -26.600     -75.583
3   2003-01 101             310.516129  304.677419  -1.880324   39.580      -69.010
4   2003-01 111             268.071429  274.000000  2.211564    -24.800     -89.983
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
153 2003-12 400             294.733333  300.000000  1.786926    11.450      -70.450
154 2003-12 454             298.176667  294.000000  -1.400736   -67.106     -68.130
155 2003-12 473             308.433333  316.000000  2.453258    -70.850     -53.140
156 2003-12 478             309.306667  304.000000  -1.715665   76.380      -69.370
```

Where `Date` is in datetime format.

I want to create 4 plots: one each for a three month period, starting from Jan-Mar where `latitude` is on the x-axis, and `ratio` is on the y-axis. I want each month then to be a single line in that specific subplot.

How would I go about doing this?

So far, I have used the following method:

```
for key, grp in comp_df_complete.groupby(['Date']):
    grp = grp.sort_values(by=['latitude'])
    plt.plot(grp.latitude, grp.ratio)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Which results in the following plot:

[image]

Which is close, with the issues being it's cluttered, plus I want each month in the 4 seasons to be visible too, in 4 faceted plots. Furthermore, the legend doesn't seem to work with this method, but that's for another question:

`No artists with labels found to put in legend.  Note that artists whose label start with an underscore are ignored when legend() is called with no argument.`

What I finally would want is a figure similar to this one:

[image]

But with `latitude` on the x-axis, `ratio` on the y-axis and three lines per plot for each month in the specific season.

Comment: I'll edit the text with what I have tried.

Comment: I have added a section with what I have so far!

Comment: The column date is probably not datetime, but what is it? A string, a period, a timestamp, something else? What does `df.dtypes` say? pandas/matplotlib react differently depending on the type.

Comment: You can create 4 subplots and in each adapt your code like :   for key, grp in df.groupby(['Date']):
    grp = grp.sort_values(by=['latitude']) ;  
    crit = grp['Date'].isin(['2003-01', '2003-02', '2003-03']) ;  
    plt.plot(grp[crit].latitude, grp[crit].ratio)

Comment: @Mr.T The column date is a datetime column, I just represented it as YYYY-MM as they are monthly mean values. In the end I just want to represent the groups as the month, without the year in it.

Comment: @rehaqds Should I then make a new criteria for each of the  4*3 months I want? I can understand if I have to, but I feel like there's a more simple way to do so.

Comment: What code generates datetime objects of this format? Anyhow, I think it is the simple way to create a month and a [quarter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.quarter.html?highlight=quarter#pandas.Series.dt.quarter) column for subplotting. [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot) might make your life easier.

Comment: I computed the monthly mean values, and it is represented in this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the values in Date are strings, the idea is to add a column giving the 'season' and for each, group by Date to get the lines for every month of a given season:

```
df['season'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: (int(x[-2:])-1)//3+1)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 12))

for i in range(4):  
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, i+1)
    for key, grp in df[df['season']==i+1].groupby(['Date']):
        grp = grp.sort_values(by=['latitude'])
        ax.plot(grp.latitude, grp.ratio)
plt.show()
```

**Edit**: if 'Date' is a datetime -> df['season'] = df['Date'].dt.quarter

Comment: The values in the date column are datetime fomat

Comment: The equivalent for datetime objects would be `df["season"] = df['Date'].dt.month.apply(lambda x: (x-1)//3+1)`

Answer (score -1):

This should help you.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Intitialise data of lists
data = [{'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':1000, 'ID':'123'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':3000, 'ID':'123'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':7000, 'ID':'123'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':3000, 'ID':'456'},
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':5000, 'ID':'456'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':5000, 'ID':'456'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':5000, 'ID':'789'},
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Expense':6000, 'ID':'789'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

uniques = df['ID'].unique()

for i in uniques:
    df_single = df[df['ID']==i]
    sns.lineplot(data=df_single, x='Month', y='Expense')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]